# child-theme style not changing on localhost

Tags: css

It's my first time working with WordPress. I have created a child theme in order to style a footer better.

I've added custom style to `style.css` and it worked great until it didn't. Now, all of a sudden, it doesn't load any changes I make to `style.css`.

**I have even deleted `style.css` and nothing changed.**

How can I fix it ? I've cleared my cache, I've reloaded using CTRL+F5. This is localhost on XAMPP.

I can't clear the cache every time I make a change to `style.css` and I will make a lot of changes to `style.css` until the website is finished.

This is my `functions.php`:

```
<?php
// add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );
// function enqueue_parent_styles() {
//    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
// }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), NULL, filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' ) );
}
?>
```

I have found this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/173076/198154

But I have no idea where to put the code:

```
<?php
$file = get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' )
    . '?' . filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' );
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $file; ?>" type="text/css" />
```

In what file does that go ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri() . '?v=' . filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css' ) );
}
```

Comment: Should I replace all I've got in `functions.php` with that ?

Comment: No, it is only a new version of `enqueue_child_theme_styles` function. Keep the `add_action` and others untouched.

Comment: Nope. It still doesn't update the style. Can you please edit your answer and type in exactly what I should have inside `functions.php` ? That would really help. Thank you.

Comment: I've even deleted `style.css` and nothing happens. How is this possible ?

Comment: This definitely looks like the style is still served from the cache. I'd rather add something like `Pragma: no-cache` header via the Apache config to prevent any caching of development version.

Comment: Now I've got multiple versions of `style.css` that are linked to the website: 
https://i.postimg.cc/QtFrPgBP/wtf.png

Comment: I do not know where to add `Pragma: no-cache`.

Comment: I have added ```<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0
</IfModule>```
Into **xampp>htdocs>website>.htaccess** and it still loads multiple versions of style files. I am reloading using CTRL+F5

Comment: I do not use Apache for years, but looks like it is a right way to add headers via Apache config.

Comment: Unfortunately it still loads multiple versions of `style.css`